# How to convert action from Quotation to Sales order when sale confirm For odoo 10

Tags: action, odoo, odoo-10

I am entering data in Quotation screen and i want that when i confirm sale for this Quotation than screen should be move to Sales Order menu. Firstly i got the action id for both action(Quotation and Sales order). But i facing problem that how to pass this action id in action_confirm method? Is there any solution for this type problem?

**This is my code:**

```
@api.multi
def action_confirm(self):
    if self.partner_id.pet_names:
        for record in self.partner_id.pet_names:
        if record == self.pet_names_info:
            if self.order_line:
                for s in self.order_line:
                    if s.product_id:
                        if self.ser1 or self.ind_ser1:
                            self.confirm_rental_service()  # Rental service
                            self.confirm_rental_service_history()  # Rental history maintain
                        break
                res = super(sale_order_pet, self).action_confirm()
                if res:
                    self.confirm_email_template()
                action = self.env.ref('sale.action_orders').read()[0]
                action['res_id'] = self.ids[0]
                action['name'] = 'Sales Order'
                return action
            else:
                raise ValidationError("Please Add Products in Order Lines")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`sale.action_orders` action invocation looks fine to me.
Have you tried to debug your code or just try to see whether it passes through all the if/else statements required to reach the `action = self.env.ref('sale.action_orders').read()[0]` statement?

What does Odoo return when you try to confirm the quotation / order?

According to your code, I guess that res.partner's `pet_names` might be a one2many field: is sale.order's `pet_names_info` a record belonging to the same class of pet_names? pet_names_info suggests something like a text field, not a one2many field.

Furthermore, comparing two records in conditional statement sounds a bit weird IMHO.

PS: by the way - naive question - is the first "if" statement closed by an "else" code chunk?

Comment: Hi dbrus, Remaining code working fine and after print action i getting right action id = '240' which is Sales Order id. Still it is not changed to Sales Order. Please find anything else missing in return action? Thanks.

Comment: What does it happen when you confirm the order?
Does it return the order's form view?
Can you the access to the `action` variable dictionary just before being returned by the `action_confirm` and please paste it here?
I guess you might somehow replace the `res_id` key-value with something like this:  `action['domain'] = [('id', 'in', ids)]`